# Code in Jupyter Notebook is not running in Python 2.7.18

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I wrote a function that was running on the Jupyter Notebook. Now I want to run the same code in Python 2.7.18 but getting a Syntax error in "" part..

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
i = now.year
j = now.month
k = now.day
def concat(i, j):
    return eval(f"{i}{j}{k}")
```

Comment: Any reason why you want to use Python 2? Python 2 has reached end of life this year.

Comment: why do you want to run new stuff in python 2.7?

Comment: f-strings are not supported until Py3.6.

Comment: The reason has nothing to do with the question. I did not ask about reason

Comment: Then be aware that there are a lot of other changes between Python 2 and Python 3, for example the behaviour of `print`, `input` and `range`. You will have to tackle those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `format` alternative instead `f-string`s working in `python 3.6+`:

```
def concat(i, j):
    return eval("{}{}{}".format(i, j, k))
```

Comment: There is also a third party package [future-fstrings](https://github.com/asottile/future-fstrings#future-fstrings) which is a backport of fstrings to python<3.6.

Answer (score 0):

You're using f-strings here in python2, but this feature was introduced in python3.6
`return eval(f"{i}{j}{k}")`

You can format the output normally, or you can use the f-string emulator package for python 2: https://pypi.org/project/fstrings/

Answer (score 0):

f string only runs on Python 3.6+. If you really need to run on Python 2.7.18 maybe you need to change your string use .format or using the % operator

instead of

`eval(f"{i}{j}{k}")`

use

`eval("{0}{1}{2}".format(i,j,k))`

or the oldest

`eval("%s %s %s" % (i, j ,k)")`